# HttpContext.Current==null in CreateAsync, but not in FindByNameAsync (IUserStore)

Tags: asp.net, async-await, asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement IUserStore Identity 2 and MVC 5

In my UserStore implementation

```
public class IdentityUserStore : IIdentityUserLoginStore, IIdentityUserClaimStore, IIdentityUserRoleStore, IIdentityUserPasswordStore, IIdentityUserSecurityStampStore, IIdentityUserStore, IIdentityUserEmailStore, IDisposable
```

i am not seeing HttpContext.Current in

```
    public async Task CreateAsync(Model.Identity.IdentityUser user)
    {
        // HttpContext.Current == null here
        if (user as object == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");

        await Task.Run(() => {_userRepository.Add(user);});
        await _uow.CommitAsync();
    }
```

but it is not null in

```
    public async Task<Model.Identity.IdentityUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        // HttpContext.Current != null it has all my data
        if (userName as object == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");

        return (await _userRepository.FindByAsync(x => x.Where(y => y.UserName == userName))).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

both methods belong to same class which implements

```
 IMyIdentityUserStore : IUserStore<MyIdentityUser,Int64>
```

So basically when I go to register new user on my website, i enter email, password and after click on register button, it throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." excepton when repository trying to access DbContext stored in HttpContext.Current.Items.

What can be problem there, why it has different context for CreateAsync and FindByNameAsync?

Comment: Could you show us how you call `CreateAsync` and `FindByNameAsync`

Comment: I can't see how exactly it being called, calls occur inside of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.StoreManager class which I do not control and it is not an open source, that's actually point of that question, "how they called" and why HttpContext.Current missing.